# 4 way switch circuit with only 3 wires on middle switch

Tags: electrical, multiway-switch

I have a house built in 1967 and don't have neutral on each box. A number of years ago I switched to Insteon switches that "Paired" with each other and did not require a neutral wire. I am switching to z-wave switches and only the main switch requires a neutral.

The problem I have is this:

Box 1
Line
Load
Traveler

Box 2 (Middle)
Line
Load
Traveler

Box 3
Line
Traveler
wire to light

I changed the switches 7 years ago and don't have the original wiring diagram. The switches were always 4 way.

The question is, the middle switch only has three wires and should require 4 wires. How do I wire my 4 way switch to accommodate this?

Fancy drawing attached

[image]

Comment: Normal 3-way switches need 2 travelers unless they are "smart switches".  I suspect your legacy wiring looks vaguely like this.  https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/157752/47125. Unfortunately there is no substitute for actually mapping the circuit re: where power enters and lamp comes off, as it varies on every circuit.   Note your installation is conduit, so the usual black-red-white you see documented elsewhere won't apply.